# Combine forkJoin and activatedRoute

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have the following observable:

```
formData$ = forkJoin([
    this.httpService.getProgramsLevelsList(),
    this.httpService.getProgramsTypesList(),
    this.httpService.getQuestionnaireReasonsList()
]).pipe( tap((res: any) => { console.log(res)     }),     );
```

And this produces an object with 3 inner arrays. ie

```
{
    [arr1],
    [arr2],
    [arr3]
}
```

I also have another observable:

```
existingFormData$: Observable<UniversityApplicationsDetail> =
    this.activatedRoute.params.pipe(
        map(params => params['id']),
        filter(id => !!id),
        switchMap((id: string) => this.httpService.getUniversityApplicationsDetail(id))
);
```

And this observable grabs an id off the url (if it exists) and returns an object from the Back End.

Can I combine these 2 observables together so I get the following result:

```
{
    [arr1],
    [arr2],
    [arr3],
    {objApplication} //This might optionally be here
}
```

Comment: If the `filter` condition fails, the observable will not complete and `forkJoin` will wait forever. According to the RxJS filters [docs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/filter), you can use `takeWhile` instead to achieve completion of the observable even if the condition fails. Small note: from [RxJS v6.5+](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#650-2019-04-23) forkJoin: accepts a dictionary of sources. So you could write something like this: `forkJoin({levelList: this.httpService.getProgramsLevelsList(), typesList: .....})` for better overview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `forkJoin` you need to make sure that every observable emits a value. You could change `existingFormData$` to emit `undefined` when there is no id, instead of never emitting anything.

```
//                                                           VVVVVVVVV
existingFormData$: Observable<UniversityApplicationsDetail | undefined> =
  this.activatedRoute.params.pipe(
    map(params => params['id']),
    switchMap((id) => id 
      ? this.httpService.getUniversityApplicationsDetail(id)
      : of(undefined)));
```

You can add this to `formData$`:

```
formData$ = forkJoin([
    this.httpService.getProgramsLevelsList(),
    this.httpService.getProgramsTypesList(),
    this.httpService.getQuestionnaireReasonsList(),
    existingFormData$,
]).pipe( tap((res: any) => { console.log(res)     }),     );
```

... to get an `Observable` of a tuple, where the last element might be `undefined` or `UniversityApplicationsDetail`.

Comment: That's awesome thanks so much. Since these are api calls and they'll only emit once, using forkJoin is fine isn't it? vs using combineLatest?

Comment: Yes, it's fine. `combineLatest` should be used when you expect multiple emissions from some sources.